# Aggregate dates monthly and count conditionally in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I have a dataset as below (name:data) that includes multiple countries with multiple event types in different dates in 3 columns and 251453 rows. I want to count monthly events for each country. For example, I want to see the number of "Battles" in "Yemen" in "August"? I have 6 different event types and 8 different countries in total.

Couldn't have any advance on it despite spending hours of it. Appreciate for any guidance.

```
|event_date|        |event_type|                |country|
12 March 2021   Explosions/Remote violence;     Yemen;
12 March 2021   Explosions/Remote violence      Yemen
12 March 2021   Battles                         Afghanistan;
12 March 2021   Battles                         Afghanistan
12 March 2021   Protests                        Yemen 
12 March 2021   Protests                        Yemen
```

The output of dput (sample) dput(head(data, 20)):

```
 structure(list(event_date = 
   structure(c(420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 
   420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L, 420L), .Label = c("01 April 
    2018", "01 April 2019", "01 April 2020", "01 August 2018", "01 August 2019", 
    "01 August 2020", "01 December 2018", "01 December 2019", "01 December 2020", 
    "01 February 2019", event_type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("Battles", "Explosions/Remote violence", "Protests", "Riots", "Strategic developments", "Violence against civilians"), class = "factor"), country = structure(c(8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Colombia", "India", "Iraq", "Lebanon", "Libya", "Mali", "Yemen"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `event_date` to date class and then count number of rows for each `country`, `month` and `event_type`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(event_date = lubridate::dmy(event_date), 
         month = format(event_date, '%b-%Y')) %>%
  count(country, month, event_type)
```

In base R, you can do this with `aggregate` :

```
data$event_date <- as.Date(data$event_date, '%d %B %Y')
data$month <- format(data$event_date, '%b-%Y')
aggregate(event_date~country + month + event_type, data, length)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RonakShah. It means a lot. Does the warning message below make sense?  Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` input `event_date`.
i  153814 failed to parse.
i Input `event_date` is `lubridate::mdy(event_date)`.

Comment: @ÜmitSeven Can you try the updated answer? I could not test the answer since your `dput` did not work for me, it seems to be incomplete.